# Joomla tmp folder not writable? or open_basedir troubles?

Tags: php, joomla, file-permissions, joomla2.5, open-basedir

i'm working on this joomla site and im not able to upload any extension. if i use normal upload method i get `JFolder::create: Could not create directory
Unable to create destination` 
if i use upload from directory i get `Copy failed
JInstaller: :Install: Failed to copy file`
i have tried so many solutions found in joomla support forum but none worked for me. 
in desperation i even changed tmp ermissions into 777 and now directory permissions (i know its bad) list shows that tmp is writable but show the warning `The PHP temporary directory is not writeable by the Joomla! instance, which may cause issues when attempting to upload extensions to Joomla!. If you are having issues uploading extensions, check the '/tmp' and set it to be writeable and see if this fixes the issue.` in extensions manager-> warnings

i was wondering whether `open_basedir` in defect. In my php info file i have 
`/srv/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/:/tmp/` - `no value` . how can i know `open_basedir` is in defect? and how can i solve this extensions matter?

Answer (score 5):

The problem may be because upload_tmp_dir isn't set in php.

Look in `SITE > SYSTEM INFORMATION > PHP INFORMATION` and check if `upload_tmp_dir` has been set. If not, you need to edit php.ini

On our servers (which use open base dir), the setting is:

`upload_tmp_dir=/tmp`

This value could be different for you, depending on your server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In the Joomla Backend, go to:

*Site >> System Information >> Directory Permissions*

and see if the "tmp" folder says "Writable"

I had the same problem with one of my shared hosts. The issue was that even though I had set literally everything to 777 (purely for testing purposes), I didn't have file ownership. If this is the case for you too, then you will have to talk to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set permission to 777
2. use **full path** for logs and tmp e.g.:
           /var/www/vhosts/mydomain/httpdocs/tmp